# how to adjust the focus when use the GPUImage framework

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I use GPUImage frameWork in my project.but I don't know how to adjust the focus of camera.is there any api can do this in the framework or other ways?

Comment: I use GPUImageStillCamera to develop my own camera. but I can't find the api  to adjust the focus also I can't set the frame. I have read the code of GPUImageStillCamera class and it's superClass. of course, I googled  the question already. sadly, my english is not so good, I don't really understand what the documents says. maybe I should read it one more time. so, if you know how to solve this problem or where I can find a solution , please tell me. tank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer in Swift. In GPUImage, the GPUImageVideoCamera class encompasses pretty much the whole AVFoundation camera pipeline. So normally to adjust the camera focus in AVFoundation you'd say:

```
var camera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
var focus: Float = 0.5

do {
    try camera.lockForConfiguration()
    camera.setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition(focus, completionHandler: nil)
    camera.unlockForConfiguration()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

In GPUImage the AVCaptureDevice is encompassed as the `inputCamera` instance property of the `GPUImageVideoCamera` class, so you would say:

```
var camera = GPUImageVideoCamera(sessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh, cameraPosition: .Back)
var focus: Float = 0.5

do {
    try camera.inputCamera.lockForConfiguration()
    camera.inputCamera.setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition(focus, completionHandler: nil)
    camera.inputCamera.unlockForConfiguration()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Changing the `AVCaptureFocusMode` is accomplished in the same way.